# Clear all system process from guest user ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am currently logged into guest user because I cannot login to my own account. I have android studio running and that is why when i login everything goes black. how can i kill all of the processes from guest user? thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK. so all i did was create a new user and copy all files and delete it. now it seems to work.